# Concatenate the values in column "Value1 - Value9" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

Data in "dbo.SampleTable" is in following format where all columns except PersonID have varchar datatype while PersonID is int:

[image]

Expected Output after concatenation of all values in the columns "value1 to value3":

[image]

There are no restriction on how the data in input table is transformed into output table.

A new table can be created as output table

Comment: Why you want to do that? Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: Have a look at [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: string_agg does not give the required result for Value1 and Value2 column. I either get "Lorem;Ipsum" or "XYZ;BLANK;BLANK" in Value 2 column after adding null handler (ISNULL)

Answer (score 0):

select DISTINCT Personid,STUFF((SELECT ','+Value1  from #temp t where t.Personid = tt.Personid FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
,STUFF((SELECT ','+Value2  from #temp t where t.Personid = tt.Personid FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
,STUFF((SELECT ','+Value3  from #temp t where t.Personid = tt.Personid FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
 from #temp tt

Comment: Nope, string_agg gives better results but not the required output